# How to write logic inside HTML tag in laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to make my `<li>` tag active , for that i wanted to check if `$category->id == $product->category_id` if equals then the class would be active otherwise inactive. How do i do it inside blade? I have done the following way.But i couldn't get proper output.

```
<li  class="{!! ($category->id == $product->category_id) ? 'active': '' !!}">
```

Comment: It's probably just a typo (`caregory_id` => `category_id`). Otherwise this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close:

```
<li  class="{{ ($category->id == $product->category_id ? 'active': '') }}">
```

You need `{{`, not `{!!`.  I also fixed a typo with `category_id`.

Comment: `{!!` should be fine as well. Not neccessary, but it should work I believe

Comment: True.  Probably the typo fix then